# How to edit XML query for SSRS 2012 RDL

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I need to modify the query of an RDL that is using a shared data source. I'm only familiar with setting up datasources for reports in Visual Studio for Business, with an embedded datasource. When I open the RDL in VS and look at the dataset's properties, "Use a shared dataset" is selected and below that the dataset is listed with a URL. When I go to that URL I am able to navigate to the datasource name and it displays as XML in IE. I have no idea where to go from there - how to modify the query. This is for SQL Server 2012 and I can only find MS articles for the latest versions - not even for 2014.

We believe that the client created this report on their own in Report Builder (which I have never used - again, I've just worked with reports in VSB), so is that the only way to modify this?

Answer (score 0):

You keep saying datasource, but what I think you mean is dataset.
So, i'm going to go on the assumption that you need to edit an embedded dataset.

Go to the embedded link and download report builder 3: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6116

Start report builder, open your rdl by clicking on the icon in the upper left corner and selecting "Open" and then navigate to your rdl.

Once the report is opened you should see a "Report Data" hierarchy pane on the left.  If not, select "View" from the menu at top and click the "Report Data" item so that it is checked.

In the Report Data pane you will see several hierarchy items, double-click the "Datasets" item to view the datasets being used in the report.  You will have to identify which dataset is the one that you need to edit, if there is more than one.

Double-click the dataset name and this will open the Dataset properties window.
in the Query Type area you should see the SQL code you will need to edit.

It's really not a good practice to embed the SQL code like this, it really should be a stored procedure.

Good luck!